# make and rosmake

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between `make` and `rosmake`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194690/make-and-rosmake/) by [kohei  ulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20433/kohei--ulu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a `rosbuild` setup (i.e. when using `rosmake`). `make` is just the standard make, which will build your package only. It will not build any dependencies nor will it realize that any dependencies have changed.

The safe way is to use `rosmake`. If you do that once and only change your package, using `make` for that should be safe.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1